# constraint issue in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

i am creating database in sqlite i create new database with constraint notnull and unique and save it to the place where is my application then i add things from my application and i check them in Library, Application support/.../..../... when i check database which is just created there then there this database is without Constraint and it accept same data.

why this is happening?

how can i make this database with Constraints just same like i have created while making application database

yes i have tried deleting database and making again

plz suggest something

Comment: delete the database from there, and run your application once again. Or reset your simulator

Comment: man man i deleted database but still this is happening thats why i am asking question why this is happening

Comment: did you added the changed database file to your project ?

Comment: well well i did this all things but let me try again

Comment: Which file you edited ? The file in bundle or the file in library/application Support/... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two problems generally causes this sort of behavior (where you're updating a database and you're not seeing this propagated to the app):

1. The db in the bundle is not getting updated. You can check this by running app on simulator, opening bundle (go to the app in Finder, ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/..., and select the app itself and choose "Show Package Contents"), and examining the db directly at that location. Bottom line, Xcode sometimes does not update the bundle properly for files altered outside of Xcode itself. This is fixed by selecting "Clean" from Xcode's "Product" menu, and then rebuilding and reinstalling the app.
2. The db that app is loading is not a copy of the version in the bundle. It doesn't sound like this is your problem, but many first time developers will copy the db from bundle to `Documents` folder if the file is not already there, neglecting to remember that when you install the app again, the contents of the `Documents` folder is preserved, and thus you'll still have the old version there. Just uninstall the app or reset the simulator if you're trying to address this for testing purposes.

   Longer term, the app itself needs some logic that looks up the version number of the database (I create a "configuration" table with this information) in the `Documents` folder, compares that to what version the app expected to find, and if different, upgrade the database in the `Documents` folder.

Bottom line, it's useful to check all three databases (project directory, bundle, and app's `Documents` folder) to see at which step you lost your database changes.